# React Native drawer navigation options set lock and unlocked dynamically?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm really new to RN and just trying out stuffs. Been trying to achieve lock and unlock drawer items dynamically based on certain condition using drawerLockMode but not working.

```
    global.navigationOptions = {
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-open'
}

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  NewScreen: {
    screen: NewScreen
  }
},
  navigationOptions = global.navigationOptions);
```

In another part, trying to change navigationOptions.drawerLockMode based on random generated number > threshold to change the lock/unlock status. I know I'm probably in the wrong direction. Can anyone please advice?Thanks in advance